# React повторно монтирует компонент, но второй раз не передает props

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class AsideNav extends Component{
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        navigation: ''
    };
}

componentWillMount(){
  console.log(this.props.data.navigation); // данные от родителя пришли
    this.setState({
        navigation:  this.props.data.navigation.map(function(el, index){
            return(
                <Link key={index} className={"aside-nav__link " + (el.modifier ? ("aside-nav__link" + el.modifier) : '')} to={el.url}>{el.name}</Link>
            )
        })
    })
}



render() {
    console.log(this.state.navigation); // JSX для меню готов
    return (
        <nav className="aside-nav">
            <span className="aside-nav__title" >Категории</span>
                {this.state.navigation}
        </nav>
    );
}

}

export default AsideNav
```

После (казалось бы) успешного выполнения кода он отображает мне пустой блок и "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined
at AsideNav.componentWillMount..."

Пробовал менять стейт на разных этапах жизненого цикла компонента проверял родительские компоненты,не работает :(
Бьюсь четвертый час, может кто намекнет где копать?)

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Читал. Я пробовал менять WillMount на DidMount  и просто перебирать props в рендере. Не работает.

Comment: Если представить что `data` не существует при инициализации, то код `this.props.data.navigation` может вызвать ошибку, так как у `undefined` нет свойства `navigation`. О чем и говорит ошибка. и хранить компоненты в state это плохо.

Comment: Согласен. В конце уже пробовал все подряд от безысходности)
Обсуждение переехало сюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384033/react-twice-mount-component-but-on-second-time-doesnt-receive-props/43384430?noredirect=1#comment73831526_43384430

Comment: я так понял Вам там дали уже ответ и Вы свою проблему решили?

Comment: Дискуссия продолжается под вторым ответом. Проблема все еще не решена)

Comment: какую версию react-route Вы используете и покажите код, который Вы используете теперь.

Comment: Версия 3.10.10

https://www.dropbox.com/home/app/page-templates?preview=page-dashboard.js
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fj9ozz4fyrmc0z/main-content.js?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj6xzax4kkku1cb/sidebar.js?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jnwiu37ef1clsbq/AABEGiAVOAFzEflSn6zYNGIHa?dl=0

В этих четырех файлах весь путь данных, которые должны отобразиться в сайдбар-меню. На данный момент ошибки нет, но и функция renderLinks() не выполняется

Comment: Если вдруг Вам на на инглишной версии не смогут помочь, то можете выложить код (тем более что всего 4файла) здесь и тогда я постараюсь Вам помочь. А так я не люблю по ссылкам ходить.

Comment: Начав склеивать четыре файла чтобы выложить сюда, решил добавить пятый (индексный) для полноты картины и наткнулся там на это:

`(<PageDashboard />, document.querySelector('.main-wrapper'));

render(  
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/public/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/public/rating" component={PageRating} />
    </Router>, document.querySelector('.main-wrapper')
);`

Вообщем, проблема решена) Я сам того не зная пытался при загрузке отрендерить два компонента, у которых есть общие дети.